# Computation of a binomial probability: nan result

Tags: binomial-distribution, python, computational-statistics

I am computing binomial probabilities for many parameters. I am using the library scipy.stats:

```
b = scipy.stats.binom(n,p)
probability = b.pmf(k)
```

I have noticed that the result is `nan` when both n and p are 0. This raises errors in my program, so I replaced nan by 0, since the probability is 0. Is this a good replacement in your opinion?

Comment: Can you (briefly) explain what that code's doing?

Comment: It is computing binomial probabilities for many 'instances'. I have objects following a binomial distribution and I want to know how likely new objects belong to this category

Comment: I meant what are `n`, `k`, `b.pmf` &c.? At a guess you're asking about the probability of $k$ successes when the probability of each success $p$ is zero & the no. of trials $n$ is zero. Are you then asking if the probability of $k$ is zero for all values of $k$?

Comment: @Scortchi you guessed right about n,p and k. What I am asking however is the following: when p=0, scipy.stats.binomial returns 'nan' (probability of k successes). This is bad for my program because I need to multiply probabilities. Therefore, I replaced this 'nan' when p=0 by 0 (probability of k successes). Is that better explained?

Comment: I don't think your solution is good and I wonder why do you need this? What use is there in doing *anything* when there are 0 trials? You could just as well as it should be 1 as 0 - the probability of 0 successes in 0 trials is 1, isn't it?

Comment: If there are 0 trials, `nan` seems like a good answer.

Comment: @Scortchi I think the probability when N=0 and K=0 depends on the problem. I thought about my case again and defined it to be equal to 0

Comment: @bigTree: I'm curious why. You can choose not to consider the case of $n=0$ at all, but if you do then anything answering to the name of the probability that $(K=k)$ has to sum to one over all values of $k$.

Comment: @Glen_b: Each bird lays $N$ eggs in its nest, where $N\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\mu)$. Each egg has probability $p$ of hatching. Simulate the distribution of $K$, the no. eggs in each nest. You require $\Pr(K=0|N=0)=1$ for this.

Comment: Note that in R `dbinom(0,0,0)` sensibly returns `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Pr(K=k)$ clearly can't be zero for *all* values of $k$. The binomial probability mass function is
$$
\Pr(K=k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\qquad\text{for }k = 0, \ldots , n\\
$$
So plug in $p=0$:.
$$
\Pr(K=k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}0^k(1)^{n-k}\qquad\text{for }k = 0, \ldots , n\\
$$
So $f(k)=0$ for $k = 1,\ldots, n$. The trouble is in evaluating $0^0$, which is undefined. You have to argue that when $p$ gets very small, the expression $p^0(1-p)^{n}$ tends to 1. It's intuitively sensible: consider how many heads you'll count (with certainty) when you toss a coin with tails on both faces.

The case $n=0$ is unproblematic: $\Pr(K=0)=1$. As @Peter says, if you don't even toss the coin, you're sure not to get any heads.

Comment: In most cases it is most useful to define $0^0=1$. Donald Knuth has argued for this.